# MikroORM not connect to my PostgreSQL server, with an error: throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE

Tags: postgresql, mikro-orm

### Here is the console:

```
P:\.Projektek\lireddit-server>yarn dev
    yarn run v1.22.10
    $ nodemon dist/index.js
    [nodemon] 2.0.7
    [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
    [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
    [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
    [nodemon] starting `node dist/index.js`
    [discovery] ORM entity discovery started, using ReflectMetadataProvider
    [discovery] - processing entity Post
    [discovery] - entity discovery finished, found 1 entities, took 29 ms
    internal/crypto/keys.js:322
        throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
        ^
    
    TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "key" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, or KeyObject. Received null
        at prepareSecretKey (internal/crypto/keys.js:322:11)
        at new Hmac (internal/crypto/hash.js:111:9)
        at Object.createHmac (crypto.js:147:10)
        at createHMAC (P:\.Projektek\lireddit-server\node_modules\pg\lib\sasl.js:133:17)
        at Hi (P:\.Projektek\lireddit-server\node_modules\pg\lib\sasl.js:137:13)
        at Object.continueSession (P:\.Projektek\lireddit-server\node_modules\pg\lib\sasl.js:32:24)
        at Client._handleAuthSASLContinue (P:\.Projektek\lireddit-server\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:257:10)       
        at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)
        at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
        at P:\.Projektek\lireddit-server\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:115:12 {
      code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
    }
    [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I don't know what to do, plz help :c

> Btw im doin Ben Awad's fullstack 14 hour long tutorial
> My Postgresql server looks fine, idk what can be the problem, but if you no anything plz tell it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have password protected postgres instance but you are not providing the password.

```
import { Options } from '@mikro-orm/core';

const config: Options = {
  migrations: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "./migrations"), // path to the folder with migrations
    pattern: /^[\w-]+\d+\.[tj]s$/, // regex pattern for the migration files       
  },
  entities: [Post],
  dbName : 'lireddit',
  type: 'postgresql',
  password: "s3xy",
  debug: !__prod__,
};

export default config;
```

Source: https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/issues/866#issuecomment-720791720

Answer (score 0):

ok, even i have faced this issue. Problem from my end was that database name was spelled incorrectly in my config file.

Here you can do following things.

```
1.Make sure you have postgres server running

2.Make sure you have created the db of lireddit. 

3.Type \conninfo in your postgres terminal it will give details such has database,portnumber and so on.
```

Hope that helps if not lemme know will guide you. Cheers!